# Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators

Tags: python, iterator, generator

What is the difference between iterators and generators? Some examples for when you would use each case would be helpful.

Answer (score 804):

`iterator` is a more general concept: any object whose class has a `__next__` method (`next` in Python 2) and an `__iter__` method that does `return self`.

Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa.  A generator is built by calling a function that has one or more `yield` expressions (`yield` statements, in Python 2.5 and earlier), and is an object that meets the previous paragraph's definition of an `iterator`.

You may want to use a custom iterator, rather than a generator, when you need a class with somewhat complex state-maintaining behavior, or want to expose other methods besides `__next__` (and `__iter__` and `__init__`).  Most often, a generator (sometimes, for sufficiently simple needs, a generator *expression*) is sufficient, and it's simpler to code because state maintenance (within reasonable limits) is basically "done for you" by the frame getting suspended and resumed.

For example, a generator such as:

```
def squares(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        yield i * i

generator = squares(a, b)
```

or the equivalent generator expression (genexp)

```
generator = (i*i for i in range(a, b))
```

would take more code to build as a custom iterator:

```
class Squares(object):
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
       self.start = start
       self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self): 
        return self

    def __next__(self): # next in Python 2
       if self.start >= self.stop:
           raise StopIteration
       current = self.start * self.start
       self.start += 1
       return current


iterator = Squares(a, b)
```

But, of course, with class `Squares` you could easily offer extra methods, i.e.

```
def current(self):
    return self.start
```

if you have any actual need for such extra functionality in your application.

Comment: Can you clarify what the correct lingo is here. I hear a lot of people using the term "Generator" interchangeably with "Generator Function" and "Generator Expression", like in a Generator Function *is* a Generator and a Generator Expression *is* a Generator. They call a "Generator Object" the special type of Iterator a Generator Function returns.  I am confused.

Comment: Even more fun is that when type hinting a Generator that only yields values can be annotated as an [Iterator more simply](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) (ie: `Generator[int, None, None]` === `Iterator[int]`)

Comment: Iterator offering objects (containers) do not need to `return self`. They also can return an instance of another object capable of iteration. If your container object returns itself, it has no clue how it's being iterated. You can't create two independent iterations at all. In most cases you should return the iter of a tuple of your objects to iterate over.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner Good question.  You may have heard the term "lazy" (as-needed) vs "eager" (at-once) evaluation.   Generators are "lazy".  They are actually sub-programs that we create.  (so a "generator function" creates a sub-program, which is a "generator")  In the example above `squares(a,b)` is a "generator function" if you run it it outputs *not* a series of square numbers, but a "generator" that can be called at will to generate those numbers.   (This is very useful when you want to control processing and memory allotment.)

Answer (score 213):

> ## What is the difference between iterators and generators? Some examples for when you would use each case would be helpful.

In summary: Iterators are objects that have an `__iter__` and a `__next__` (`next` in Python 2) method. Generators provide an easy, built-in way to create instances of Iterators.

A function with yield in it is still a function, that, when called, returns an instance of a generator object:

```
def a_function():
    "when called, returns generator object"
    yield
```

A generator expression also returns a generator:

```
a_generator = (i for i in range(0))
```

For a more in-depth exposition and examples, keep reading.

### A Generator *is* an Iterator

Specifically, generator is a subtype of iterator.

```
>>> import collections, types
>>> issubclass(types.GeneratorType, collections.Iterator)
True
```

We can create a generator several ways. A very common and simple way to do so is with a function.

Specifically, a function with yield in it is a function, that, when called, returns a generator:

```
>>> def a_function():
        "just a function definition with yield in it"
        yield
>>> type(a_function)
<class 'function'>
>>> a_generator = a_function()  # when called
>>> type(a_generator)           # returns a generator
<class 'generator'>
```

And a generator, again, is an Iterator:

```
>>> isinstance(a_generator, collections.Iterator)
True
```

### An Iterator *is* an Iterable

An Iterator is an Iterable,

```
>>> issubclass(collections.Iterator, collections.Iterable)
True
```

which requires an `__iter__` method that returns an Iterator:

```
>>> collections.Iterable()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>
    collections.Iterable()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Iterable with abstract methods __iter__
```

Some examples of iterables are the built-in tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets, frozen sets, strings, byte strings, byte arrays, ranges and memoryviews:

```
>>> all(isinstance(element, collections.Iterable) for element in (
        (), [], {}, set(), frozenset(), '', b'', bytearray(), range(0), memoryview(b'')))
True
```

### Iterators *require* a `next` or `__next__` method

In Python 2:

```
>>> collections.Iterator()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#80>", line 1, in <module>
    collections.Iterator()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Iterator with abstract methods next
```

And in Python 3:

```
>>> collections.Iterator()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Iterator with abstract methods __next__
```

We can get the iterators from the built-in objects (or custom objects) with the `iter` function:

```
>>> all(isinstance(iter(element), collections.Iterator) for element in (
        (), [], {}, set(), frozenset(), '', b'', bytearray(), range(0), memoryview(b'')))
True
```

The `__iter__` method is called when you attempt to use an object with a for-loop. Then the `__next__` method is called on the iterator object to get each item out for the loop. The iterator raises `StopIteration` when you have exhausted it, and it cannot be reused at that point.

### From the documentation

From the Generator Types section of the Iterator Types section of the Built-in Types [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

> Python’s **generators provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol.** If a container object’s `__iter__()` method is implemented as a generator, it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object) supplying the `__iter__()` and `next()` [`__next__()` in Python 3] methods. More information about generators can be found in the documentation for the yield expression.

(Emphasis added.)

So from this we learn that Generators are a (convenient) type of Iterator.

### Example Iterator Objects

You might create object that implements the Iterator protocol by creating or extending your own object.

```
class Yes(collections.Iterator):

    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.x = 0
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.x < self.stop:
            self.x += 1
            return 'yes'
        else:
            # Iterators must raise when done, else considered broken
            raise StopIteration

    __next__ = next # Python 3 compatibility
```

But it's easier to simply use a Generator to do this:

```
def yes(stop):
    for _ in range(stop):
        yield 'yes'
```

Or perhaps simpler, a Generator Expression (works similarly to list comprehensions):

```
yes_expr = ('yes' for _ in range(stop))
```

They can all be used in the same way:

```
>>> stop = 4             
>>> for i, y1, y2, y3 in zip(range(stop), Yes(stop), yes(stop), 
                             ('yes' for _ in range(stop))):
...     print('{0}: {1} == {2} == {3}'.format(i, y1, y2, y3))
...     
0: yes == yes == yes
1: yes == yes == yes
2: yes == yes == yes
3: yes == yes == yes
```

### Conclusion

You can use the Iterator protocol directly when you need to extend a Python object as an object that can be iterated over.

However, in the vast majority of cases, you are best suited to use `yield` to define a function that returns a Generator Iterator or consider Generator Expressions.

Finally, note that generators provide even more functionality as coroutines. [I explain Generators, along with the `yield` statement, in depth on my answer to "What does the “yield” keyword do?".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31042491/541136)

Comment: `generators provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol` - so there is no specific generator protocol in python, only iterator protocol that covers generators as well?

Answer (score 57):

**Iterators** are objects which use the `next()` method to get the following values of a sequence.

**Generators** are functions that produce or yield a sequence of values using the `yield` keyword.

Every `next()` method call on a generator object(for ex: `f` below) returned by a generator function (for ex: `foo()` below), generates the next value in the sequence.

When a generator function is called, it returns an generator object without even beginning the execution of the function. When the `next()` method is called for the first time, the function starts executing until it reaches a `yield` statement which returns the yielded value. The `yield` keeps track of what has happened, i.e. it remembers the last execution. And secondly, the `next()` call continues from the previous value.

The following example demonstrates the interplay between `yield` and the call to the `next` method on a generator object.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("begin")
...     for i in range(3):
...         print("before yield", i)
...         yield i
...         print("after yield", i)
...     print("end")
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> next(f)
begin
before yield 0            # Control is in for loop
0
>>> next(f)
after yield 0             
before yield 1            # Continue for loop
1
>>> next(f)
after yield 1
before yield 2
2
>>> next(f)
after yield 2
end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: Just FYI yield is not method, it's keyword

Answer (score 44):

Adding an answer because none of the existing answers specifically address the confusion in the official literature.

***Generator functions*** are ordinary functions defined using `yield` instead of `return`. When called, a generator function returns a ***generator object***, which is a kind of iterator - it has a `next()` method. When you call `next()`, the next value yielded by the generator function is returned.

Either the function or the object may be called the "generator" depending on which Python source document you read. The [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) says generator functions, while the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) implies generator objects. The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) remarkably manages to imply *both* usages in the space of three sentences:

> Generators are a simple and powerful tool for creating iterators. They are written like regular functions but use the yield statement whenever they want to return data. Each time next() is called on it, the generator resumes where it left off (it remembers all the data values and which statement was last executed).

The first two sentences identify generators with generator functions, while the third sentence identifies them with generator objects.

Despite all this confusion, one can seek out the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) for the clear and final word:

> The yield expression is only used when defining a generator function, and can only be used in the body of a function definition. Using a yield expression in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function.
>
> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function.

So, in formal and precise usage, ***"generator" unqualified means generator object, not generator function.***

The above references are for Python 2 but [Python 3 language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) says the same thing. However, the [Python 3 glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) states that

> **generator** ... Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts. In cases where the intended meaning isn’t clear, using the full terms avoids ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think there's much confusion between generator functions and generator objects, for the same reason there's usually no confusion between classes and their instances. In both cases, you call one to get the other, and in casual conversation (or quickly written documentation) you can use the class name or the word "generator" for either one. You only need to be explicit about "generator function" versus "generator object" in rare situations where which one you're talking about matters.

Comment: 1. Regardless of theoretical reasons for why there shouldn't be confusion, comments on other answers to this question deny and contradict one another without resolution, indicating actual confusion exists. 2. Casual imprecision is fine but a precise, authoritative source should at least be one of the options on SO. I use both generator functions and objects extensively in my current project, and the distinction is very important when designing and coding. It's good to know what terminology to use now, so I don't have to change dozens of variable names and comments later on.

Comment: Imagine a mathematics literature where no distinction is made between a function and its return value. It is occasionally convenient to conflate them informally, but it increases the risk of a variety of mistakes. Advanced modern mathematics would be significantly and needlessly hampered if the distinction were not formalized in convention, language, and notation.

Comment: Sure, specific language is good. But there's hardly any time in discussing *actual code* where you could refer to a "generator" and not know if it meant a generator object or a generator function (or generator expression, an extra version that you haven't mentioned). I suppose a higher-order function using generator-function arguments would ambiguous if you used sloppy language (since a "generator" argument almost always means passing a generator object), but I'm not sure I've ever seen such a thing, never mind discussing it in prose.

Comment: Higher-order functions passing around generators or generator functions may sound weird, but for me they have been coming up. I'm working in Apache Spark and it enforces a very functional programming style. The functions have to create, pass in, and pass out all sorts of objects to get things done. I've had a number of situations where I lost track of what kind of "generator" I was working with. Hints in variable names and comments, using the consistent and correct terminology, helped clear up the confusion.

One Pythonist's obscurity can be the center of another's project design!

Comment: @Paul, thanks for writing this answer. This confusion is important because the difference between a generator object and a generator function is the difference between getting the desired behavior and having to lookup generators.

Comment: A generator function yields a generator object.  What's confusing about that. :)

Answer (score 33):

Everybody has a really nice and verbose answer with examples and I really appreciate it. I just wanted to give a short few lines answer for people who are still not quite clear conceptually:

*If you create your own iterator, it is a little bit involved - you have 
to create a class and at least implement the iter and the next methods. But what if you don't want to go through this hassle and want to quickly create an iterator. Fortunately, Python provides a short-cut way to defining an iterator. All you need to do is define a function with at least 1 call to yield and now when you call that function it will return "**something**" which will act like an iterator (you can call next method and use it in a for loop). This **something** has a name in Python called Generator*

Hope that clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 17):

Examples from  [Ned Batchelder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o) highly recommended for iterators and generators

A method without generators that do something to even numbers

```
def evens(stream):
   them = []
   for n in stream:
      if n % 2 == 0:
         them.append(n)
   return them
```

while by using a generator

```
def evens(stream):
    for n in stream:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield n
```

- We don't need any **list** nor a **`return`** statement
- Efficient for large/ infinite length stream ... it just walks and yield the value

Calling the `evens` method (generator) is as usual

```
num = [...]
for n in evens(num):
   do_smth(n)
```

- Generator also used to Break double loop

***Iterator***

> A book full of pages is an **iterable**,  A bookmark is an
>   **iterator**

and this bookmark has nothing to do except to move `next`

```
litr = iter([1,2,3])
next(litr) ## 1
next(litr) ## 2
next(litr) ## 3
next(litr) ## StopIteration  (Exception) as we got end of the iterator
```

To use Generator ... we need a function

To use Iterator  ...  we need `next` and `iter`

As been said:

> A Generator function returns an iterator object

The Whole benefit of Iterator:

> Store one element a time in memory

Comment: About your first code snippet, I'd like to know what else arg 'stream' could be than the list[]?

Answer (score 14):

Previous answers missed this addition: a generator has a `close` method, while typical iterators don’t. The `close` method triggers a `StopIteration` exception in the generator, which may be caught in a `finally` clause in that iterator, to get a chance to run some clean‑up. This abstraction makes it most usable in the large than simple iterators. One can close a generator as one could close a file, without having to bother about what’s underneath.

That said, my personal answer to the first question would be: iteratable has an `__iter__` method only, typical iterators have a `__next__` method only, generators has both an `__iter__` and a `__next__` and an additional `close`.

For the second question, my personal answer would be: in a public interface, I tend to favor generators a lot, since it’s more resilient: the `close` method an a greater composability with `yield from`. Locally, I may use iterators, but only if it’s a flat and simple structure (iterators does not compose easily) and if there are reasons to believe the sequence is rather short especially if it may be stopped before it reach the end. I tend to look at iterators as a low level primitive, except as literals.

For control flow matters, generators are an as much important concept as promises: both are abstract and composable.

Comment: Could you give an example to illustrate you mean when talking about composition? Also, can you explain what you have in mind when talking about "*typical* iterators"?

Comment: Another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353158/1878788) states that "an iterator is an iterable". Since an iterable has an `__iter__` method, how come an iterator can have `__next__` only? If they are supposed to be iterables, I would expect them to necessarily have `__iter__` too.

Comment: @bli: AFAICS this answer here [refers to the standard PEP234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), so it is correct, while the the other answer refers to some implementation, so it is questionable.  The standard only requires an `__iter__` on iterables to return an iterator, which only requires a `next` method (`__next__` in Python3).  Please do not confuse standards (for duck typing) with their implementation (how a particular Python interpreter implemented it).  This is a bit like the confusion between generator functions (definition) and generator objects (implementation).  ;)

Answer (score 14):

No-code 4 line cheat sheet:

```
A generator function is a function with yield in it.

A generator expression is like a list comprehension. It uses "()" vs "[]"

A generator object (often called 'a generator') is returned by both above.

A generator is also a subtype of iterator.
```

Comment: Question of clarification about #4 in the above claim.  Is it really correct?  is a generator really a subtype?  I was under the impression that a generator is an object, not a type.

Comment: @JimNewton Generator is undoubtfully an object, as you can return it (from a function), and pass it as a ref/param

Answer (score 10):

It's difficult to answer the question without 2 other concepts: `iterable` and `iterator protocol`.

1. What is difference between `iterator` and `iterable`?
   Conceptually you iterate over `iterable` with the help of corresponding `iterator`. There are a few differences that can help to distinguish `iterator` and `iterable` in practice:

   - One difference is that `iterator` has `__next__` method, `iterable` does not.
   - Another difference - both of them contain `__iter__` method. In case of `iterable` it returns the corresponding iterator. In case of `iterator` it returns itself.
     This can help to distinguish `iterator` and `iterable` in practice.

```py
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dir(x) 
[... __iter__ ...]
>>> x_iter = iter(x)
>>> dir(x_iter)
[... __iter__ ... __next__ ...]
>>> type(x_iter)
list_iterator
```

2. What are `iterables` in `python`? `list`, `string`, `range` etc. What are `iterators`? `enumerate`, `zip`, `reversed` etc. We may check this using the approach above. It's kind of confusing. Probably it would be easier if we have only one type. Is there any difference between `range` and `zip`? One of the reasons to do this - `range` has a lot of additional functionality - we may index it or check if it contains some number etc. (see details [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/)).
3. How can we create an `iterator` ourselves? Theoretically we may implement `Iterator Protocol` (see [here](https://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/#The_Iterator_Protocol)). We need to write `__next__` and `__iter__` methods and raise `StopIteration` exception and so on (see Alex Martelli's answer for an example and possible motivation, see also [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/06/how-to-make-an-iterator-in-python/)). But in practice we use generators. It seems to be by far the main method to create `iterators` in `python`.

I can give you a few more interesting examples that show somewhat confusing usage of those concepts in practice:

- in `keras` we have `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`; this class doesn't have `__next__` and `__iter__` methods; so it's not an iterator (or generator);
- if you call its `flow_from_dataframe()` method you'll get `DataFrameIterator` that has those methods; but it doesn't implement `StopIteration` (which is not common in build-in iterators in `python`); in documentation we may read that "A `DataFrameIterator` yielding tuples of `(x, y)`" - again confusing usage of terminology;
- we also have `Sequence` class in `keras` and that's custom implementation of a generator functionality (regular generators are not suitable for multithreading) but it doesn't implement `__next__` and `__iter__`, rather it's a wrapper around generators (it uses `yield` statement);

Answer (score 9):

This thread covers in many details all the differences between the two, but wanted to add something on the conceptual difference between the two:

> [...] an **iterator** as defined in the GoF book **retrieves items from a collection**, while a **generator can produce items “out of thin air”**. That’s why the Fibonacci sequence generator is a common example: an infinite series of numbers cannot be stored in a collection.

Ramalho, Luciano. Fluent Python (p. 415). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Sure, it does not cover all the aspects but I think it gives a good notion when one can be useful.

Answer (score 8):

> **Generator Function, Generator Object, Generator:**

A **Generator function** is just like a regular function in Python but it contains one or more `yield` statements. Generator functions is a great tool to create  **Iterator** objects as easy as possible.  The **Iterator** object returend by generator function is also called **Generator object** or **Generator**.

In this example I have created a Generator function which returns a Generator object `<generator object fib at 0x01342480>`. Just like other iterators, Generator objects can be used in a  `for` loop  or with   the built-in function `next()` which returns the next value from generator.

```
def fib(max):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(max):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
print(fib(10))             #<generator object fib at 0x01342480>

for i in fib(10):
    print(i)               # 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34


print(next(myfib))         #0
print(next(myfib))         #1
print(next(myfib))         #1
print(next(myfib))         #2
```

**So a generator function is the easiest way to create an Iterator object.**

> **Iterator**:

Every **generator object** is an **iterator** but not vice versa.  A custom  iterator object  can  be created if its class implements  `__iter__` and `__next__` method (also called iterator protocol).

However, it is  much easier to use generators function to create **iterators** because they simplify their creation,  but a custom Iterator gives you more freedom and you can also implement other methods according to your requirements as shown in the  below example.

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self,max):
        self.current=0
        self.next=1
        self.max=max
        self.count=0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count>self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current,self.next=self.next,(self.current+self.next)
            self.count+=1
            return self.next-self.current

    def __str__(self):
        return "Generator object"

itobj=Fib(4)
print(itobj)               #Generator object

for i in Fib(4):  
    print(i)               #0 1 1 2

print(next(itobj))         #0
print(next(itobj))         #1
print(next(itobj))         #1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can compare both approaches for the same data:

```
def myGeneratorList(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

def myIterableList(n):
    ll = n*[None]
    for i in range(n):
        ll[i] = i
    return ll

# Same values
ll1 = myGeneratorList(10)
ll2 = myIterableList(10)
for i1, i2 in zip(ll1, ll2):
    print("{} {}".format(i1, i2))

# Generator can only be read once
ll1 = myGeneratorList(10)
ll2 = myIterableList(10)

print("{} {}".format(len(list(ll1)), len(ll2)))
print("{} {}".format(len(list(ll1)), len(ll2)))

# Generator can be read several times if converted into iterable
ll1 = list(myGeneratorList(10))
ll2 = myIterableList(10)

print("{} {}".format(len(list(ll1)), len(ll2)))
print("{} {}".format(len(list(ll1)), len(ll2)))
```

Besides, if you check the memory footprint, the generator takes much less memory as it doesn't need to store all the values in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

An **iterable object** is something which can be iterated (naturally). To do that, however, you will need something like an **iterator object**, and, yes, the terminology may be confusing. Iterable objects include a `__iter__` method which will return the iterator object for the iterable object.

An iterator object is an object which implements the **iterator protocol** - a set of rules. In this case, it must have at least these two methods: `__iter__` and `__next__`. The `__next__` method is a function which supplies a new value. The `__iter__` method returns the iterator object. In a more complex object, there may be a separate iterator, but in a simpler case, `__iter__` returns the object itself (typically `return self`).

One iterable object is a `list` object. It’s not an iterator, but it has an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator. You can call this method directly as `things.__iter__()`, or use `iter(things)`.

If you want to iterate through any collection, you will need to use its iterator:

```py
things_iterator = iter(things)
for i in things_iterator:
    print(i)
```

However, Python will automatically use the iterator, which is why you never see the above example. Instead you write:

```py
for i in things:
    print(i)
```

Writing an iterator yourself can be tedious, so Python has a simpler alternative: the **generator function**. A generator function is not an ordinary function. Instead of running through the code and returning a final result, the code is deferred, and the function returns immediately with a **generator object**.

A generator object is like an iterator object in that it implements the iterator protocol. That’s good enough for most purposes. There are many examples of generators in the other answers.

In short, an iterator is an object which allows you to iterate through another object, whether it’s a collection or some other source of values. A generator is a simplified iterator which does more-or-less the same job, but is easier to implement.

Normally, you would go for a generator if that’s all you need. If, however, you’re building a more complex object which includes iteration among other features, you would use the iterator protocol instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing specifically for Python newbies in a very simple way, though deep down Python does so many things.

Let’s start with the very basic:

Consider a list,

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

Let’s write an equivalent function:

```
def f():
    return [1,2,3]
```

o/p of `print(l): [1,2,3]` &
o/p of `print(f()) : [1,2,3]`

Let’s make list l iterable: In python list is always iterable that means you can apply iterator whenever you want.

Let’s apply iterator on list:

```
iter_l = iter(l) # iterator applied explicitly
```

Let’s make a function iterable, i.e. write an equivalent generator function.
**In python as soon as you introduce the keyword `yield`; it becomes a generator function and iterator will be applied implicitly.**

*Note: Every generator is always iterable with implicit iterator applied and here implicit iterator is the crux*
So the generator function will be:

```
def f():
  yield 1 
  yield 2
  yield 3

iter_f = f() # which is iter(f) as iterator is already applied implicitly
```

So if you have observed, as soon as you made function f a generator, it is already iter(f)

Now,

> l is the list, after applying iterator method "iter" it becomes,
>   iter(l)
>
> f is already iter(f), after applying iterator method "iter" it
>   becomes, iter(iter(f)), which is again iter(f)

It's kinda you are casting int to int(x) which is already int and it will remain int(x).

For example o/p of :

```
print(type(iter(iter(l))))
```

is

```
<class 'list_iterator'>
```

***Never forget this is Python and not C or C++***

Hence the conclusion from above explanation is:

> list l ~= iter(l)
>
> generator function f == iter(f)

Answer (score 0):

All generators are iterators but not vice versa.

```py
from typing import Iterator
from typing import Iterable
from typing import Generator

class IT:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 4:
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            return self.n
        finally:
            self.n += 1


def g():
    for i in range(4):
        yield i

def test(it):
    print(f'type(it) = {type(it)}')
    print(f'isinstance(it, Generator) = {isinstance(it, Generator)}')
    print(f'isinstance(it, Iterator) = {isinstance(it, Iterator)}')
    print(f'isinstance(it, Iterable) = {isinstance(it, Iterable)}')
    print(next(it))
    print(next(it))
    print(next(it))
    print(next(it))
    try:
        print(next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        print('boom\n')


print(f'issubclass(Generator, Iterator) = {issubclass(Generator, Iterator)}')
print(f'issubclass(Iterator, Iterable) = {issubclass(Iterator, Iterable)}')
print()
test(IT())
test(g())
```

---

Output:

```py
issubclass(Generator, Iterator) = True
issubclass(Iterator, Iterable) = True

type(it) = <class '__main__.IT'>
isinstance(it, Generator) = False
isinstance(it, Iterator) = True
isinstance(it, Iterable) = True
0
1
2
3
boom

type(it) = <class 'generator'>
isinstance(it, Generator) = True
isinstance(it, Iterator) = True
isinstance(it, Iterable) = True
0
1
2
3
boom
```