# itertools.islice is not a generator?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a code piece that works on generators and generator functions. When I try to slice the generators with `itertools.islice`, the code piece generates no outputs.

I've looked into the code, and found out the following code piece:

```
if isinstance(result, dict):
    self.returned(result)
elif inspect.isgenerator(result):
    for x in result:
        self.returned(x)
else:
    self.returned(result)
```

It turns out that `inspect.isgenerator` returns `False` for `itertools.islice`, which is what breaks the code. `inspect.isgeneratorfunction` behaves the same.

1. Isn't `itertools.islice` a generator, or an generator function?
2. How can I find out of `result` is a generator OR an `itertools.islice` object?

Comment: My python version is 2.7.3 on win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

```
inspect.getmembers(itertools.islice)
```

`islice` is an iterator, not a generator. 
More info [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-python-generators-vs-iterators)

Comment: `islice` is both an iterator and a generator. Take a look at it's code here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: @iTayb I believe that is just a Python representation of what is going on under the hood, not how it is actually implemented