# Adding in python2

Tags: python, loops

This is a check digit exercise.

```
A=str(56784321)
for x in [0,2,4,6]:
    B = int(A[x])*2
        if len(str(B))==2:
            B = int(str(B)[0])+int(str(B)[1])
            print (B)
```

Output:

```
1
5
8
4
```

How can I use further code to add 4 of them together?

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your code, you can use Python [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-python-generators-vs-iterators) for a good reference.

```
def split_str(A):
  for x in [0,2,4,6]:
    B=int(A[x])*2
    if len(str(B))==2:
      B= int(str(B)[0])+int(str(B)[1])
    yield B

A=str(56784321)
for f in split_str(A):
  print f
print 'Sum is', sum(split_str(A))
```

Prints:

```
1
5
8
4
Sum is 18
```

Comment: How can you do it with out putting them into function?

Comment: @pythonBeginner, you could create an empty list before your code and append B values to it instead of yielding them. This is not that hard, you could try that yourself as an exercise.

Comment: @VladimirSinenko Thanks for your advise, but could you give me an example of creating an empty list?

Comment: It's created like this: `var = []`. You'll further need `var.append()` operator to populate the list. I suggest you to read the Python tutorial from the start.