# How to get an arbitrary element from a frozenset?

Tags: python, iterator, set, immutability

I would like to get an element from a `frozenset` (without modifying it, of course, as `frozenset`s are immutable). The best solution I have found so far is:

```
s = frozenset(['a'])
iter(s).next()
```

which returns, as expected:

```
'a'
```

In other words, is there any way of 'popping' an element from a `frozenset` without actually popping it?

Comment: I think your method is as good as any. If you want a random element you might check out `random.sample(fset, 1)`.

Comment: Why do you want to pop the element, because it's arbitrary?

Comment: I just want to get some arbitrary element from a frozenset. I shouldn't have used the word pop since the set remains unchanged. It is similar to peeking the first element of a stack without popping it.

Comment: That's what I use (but with the `next` builtin instead of the method).

Comment: Don't use the method `.next()`. There is a `next()` built-in function since at least python2.6 and using it means that your code will work also in python3 where the `next` method was renamed `__next__`.

Comment: @user2357112 and @Bakuriu: Thank you for your answers, especially Bakuriu for the explanation of the difference between `next(iter(fset))` and `iter(fset).next()`.

Comment: @Bo102010 `random.sample(fset, 1)` returns a list; you need `random.sample(fset, 1)[0]` to get the element itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*(Summarizing the answers given in the comments)*

Your method is as good as any, with the caveat that, from Python 2.6, you should be using `next(iter(s))` rather than `iter(s).next()`.

If you want a *random* element rather than an *arbitrary* one, use the following:

```
import random
random.sample(s, 1)[0]
```

Here are a couple of examples demonstrating the difference between those two:

```
>>> s = frozenset("kapow")
>>> [next(iter(s)) for _ in range(10)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.sample(s, 1)[0] for _ in range(10)]
['w', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'k', 'k', 'p', 'k']
```

Comment: Why should you call `next(iter(s))` rather than `iter(s).next()`?

Comment: @rynemccall Because in Python 3, [`iter.next()` doesn't exist](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

Answer (score 24):

If you know that there is but one element in the frozenset, you can use iterable unpacking:

```
s = frozenset(['a'])
x, = s
```

This is somewhat a special case of the original question, but it comes in handy some times.

If you have a lot of these to do it might be faster than next(iter..:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a,b = foo', setup='foo = frozenset(range(2))', number=100000000)
5.054765939712524
>>> timeit.timeit('a = next(iter(foo))', setup='foo = frozenset(range(2))', number=100000000)
11.258678197860718
```

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack` on set with multiple elements.

Comment: as said, this only works with *exactly* one element in the frozenset.

Answer (score 12):

You could use with python 3:

```
>>> s = frozenset(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> x, *_ = s
>>> x
'a'
>>> _, x, *_ = s
>>> x
'b'
>>> *_, x, _ = s
>>> x
'c'
>>> *_, x = s
>>> x
'd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `list`:

```py
list_ = list(frozenset("Benyamin"))
```

---

Using `generator`:

```py
def get_frozenset_elements(frozen_set):
    for i in frozen_set:
        yield i

gen_ = get_frozenset_elements(frozenset("Benyamin"))
next(gen_)
next(gen_)
next(gen_)
...
```

---

Using `iterator`:

```py
iter_ = iter(frozenset("Benyamin"))
next(gen_)
next(gen_)
next(gen_)
...
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

<sub>[Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776829/3702377)</sub>

Comment: The first of these is just a complicated way to write `list(my_frozenset)`, which is quite wasteful for large sets. The second is just a complicated way to write `next(iter(my_frozenset))`, which is already the accepted answer.