# Python enumerate downwards or with a custom step

Tags: python, enumerate

How to make Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to enumerate from bigger numbers to lesser (descending order, decrement, count down)? Or in general, how to use different step increment/decrement in `enumerate`?

For example, such function, applied to list `['a', 'b', 'c']`, with start value `10` and step `-2`, would produce iterator `[(10, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (6, 'c')]`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I haven't found more elegant, idiomatic, and concise way, than to write a simple generator:

```
def enumerate2(xs, start=0, step=1):
    for x in xs:
        yield (start, x)
        start += step
```

Examples:

```
>>> list(enumerate2([1,2,3], 5, -1))
[(5, 1), (4, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> list(enumerate2([1,2,3], 5, -2))
[(5, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
```

If you don't understand the above code, read [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) and [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-python-generators-vs-iterators).

Answer (score 10):

One option is to `zip` your iterable to a `range`:

```
for index, item in zip(range(10, 0, -2), ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    ...
```

This does have the limitation that you need to know how far the `range` should go (the minimum it should cover - as in my example, excess will be truncated by `zip`).

If you don't know, you could roll your own "infinite `range`" (or just use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) and use that:

```
>>> def inf_range(start, step):
    """Generator function to provide a never-ending range."""
    while True:
        yield start
        start += step

        
>>> list(zip(inf_range(10, -2), ['a', 'b', 'c']))
[(10, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (6, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idiomatic way to do that:

```
list(zip(itertools.count(10,-2), 'abc'))
```

returns:
`[(10, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (6, 'c')]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `itertools.count`, which is helpful for "enumerating" by a **step**, in **reverse**.

```
import itertools

counter = itertools.count(10, -2)
[(next(counter), letter) for letter in ["a", "b", "c"]]
# [(10, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (6, 'c')]
```

**Characteristics**

- concise
- the step and direction logic is compactly stored in `count()`
- enumerated indices are iterated with `next()`
- `count()` is inherently infinite; useful if the terminal boundary is unknown
  (see @jonrsharpe)
- the sequence length intrinsically terminates the infinite iterator

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need iterator keeped in variable and just iterate through some container, multiply your index by step.

```py
container = ['a', 'b', 'c']
step = -2

for index, value in enumerate(container):
    print(f'{index * step}, {value}')


>>> 0, a
-2, b
-4, c
```

Answer (score -1):

May be not very elegant, using f'strings the following quick solution can be handy

```py
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']
p=10
for counter, value in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f" {counter+p}, {value}")
    p+=9

> 10, apple
> 20, banana
> 30, grapes
> 40, pear
```

Comment: This seems to be a convoluted way of writing ``(counter + 1)*10``.