# Difference between send(None) and Next()

Tags: python, generator

By redefining the yield statement to be an expression in [PEP 342-- Coroutines via Enhanced Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) powerful new functionality was added to Python.  David Beasley has an excellent presentation on Python coroutines [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/).

As the PEP states, A yield expression's value is None whenever the generator is resumed by a normal next() call.  To instantiate the generator either next() or send(None) must be called (i.e. cannot send non-None value initially).

Is there any advantage in calling next() vs send(None)?  next() is a Built_in function, so perhaps that's a factor, but there doesn't seem to be any other differences.  I'm somewhat surprised, it would seem more Pythonic to add an optional variable to next than add a new function that does the same thing.  Am I missing something?

Here is a simple coroutine to keep a running total of numbers entered, by sending them to the coroutine.

```
import numbers
def running_sum() :
    g_in  = 0
    g_out = 0
    while g_in is not None :
        g_in = (yield g_out)
        if isinstance(g_in, numbers.Number) :
            g_out += g_in
        print 'in_val =',g_in,'sum =',g_out
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are missing is that [generators are a special case of iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators).

An iterator is anything which (correctly) implements the `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods.  The `__iter__()` method, in this case, is simply supposed to return the iterator itself.  The `__next__()` method is called to implement `next()`.

The key, however, is that `__next__()` *takes no arguments* (besides `self`).  The `.send()` method is not part of the iteration protocol.  In the general case, an iterator is not required to implement `.send()`.  Indeed, if you call `iter([])`, you will get an object which lacks the method.  Sending only works on true generators (functions written using the `yield` syntax).  By contrast, `next()` works on any iterator.