# Please explain the concept of generator and iterator with good examples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, I want to know the concept of **generator and iterator**

Please somebody explain what is this and how it works with some nice examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will direct you to two great answers on SO:

[Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

and

[Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Finally, this article is what finally got me to understand it properly:

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much.
Just to clear... every function which uses an yield method will be an generator right?
And in generator code when we will call next() code will execute till yield and return value from the yield, and so on..

Comment: You're on the right track. But, this is exactly what I read when I learned generators, iterators and yield. This is the article that helped me the most. I will also put it in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: thanks this post was nice.

Comment: To visualize everything, this is good tool.
http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display