# Do generators simply make new objects with __iter__ and next functions?

Tags: python

I tried to search for this answer on my own, but there was too much noise.

Are generators in python just a convenience wrapper for the user to make an iterator object?

When you define the generator:

```
def test():
  x = 0
  while True:
    x += 1
    yield x
```

is python simply making a new object, adding the `__iter__` method, then putting the rest of the code into the `next` function?

```
class Test(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def next(self):
    self.x += 1
    return self.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Like so:

```
>>> def test():
...    x = 0
...    while True:
...       x += 1
...       yield x
...
>>> type(test)
<type 'function'>
```

So what it returns is a function object.  Details from there get hairy; the short course is that the code object belonging to the function (`test.func_code`) is marked as a generator by one of the flags in `test.func_code.co_flags`.

You can disassemble the bytecode for `test` to see that it's just like any other function otherwise, apart from that a generator function always contains a `YIELD_VALUE` opcode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 34)
        >>    9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       33

  4          15 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             21 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             28 YIELD_VALUE
             29 POP_TOP
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   33 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

To do it the way you have in mind, the horrors just start ;-) if you think about how to create an object to mimic just this:

```
def test():
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield 4
```

Now your `next()` method would have to carry additional hidden state just to remember which `yield` comes next.  Wrap that in some nested loops with some conditionals, and "unrolling" it into a single-entry `next()` becomes a nightmare.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I didn't know exactly how to tell what the language was doing under the hood.

I'm glad you used the `dis` module - i knew what I was trying to look for, but couldn't come up with the phrasing to actually find the results.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll find it profitable to read the PEP in which generators were first proposed - you grasp enough now to make sense of most of it :-)  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/

Answer (score 2):

No -- Generators also provide other methods (`.send`, `.throw`, etc) and can be used for more purposes than simply making iterators (e.g. coroutines).

Indeed, `generators` are an entirely different beast and a core language feature.  It'd be very hard (possibly impossible) to create one in vanilla python if they weren't baked into the language.

---

With that said, *one* application of generators is to provide an easy syntax for creating an iterator :-).

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure if both objects boiled down to the same bytecode in the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Are generators in python just a convenience wrapper for the user to make an iterator object?

No. A `generator` is a function, where as `iterators` are class. Hence, generator can not be a object of iterator. But in some way you can say that *generator is a simplified approach to get iterator like capability*. It means:

> All Generators are iterators, but not all iterators are generators.

I will strongly suggest you refer below wiki links:

- [Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) - traverses a collection one at a time
- [Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) - generates a sequence, one item at a time

An iterator is typically something that has a `next` method to get the next element from a stream. A generator is an iterator that is tied to a function.

I will suggest you to refer: [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators).