# __next__ in generators and iterators and what is a method-wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, wrapper

I was reading about generator and iterators and the role of `__next__()` .

`'__next__' in dir(mygen)`. is true

`'__next__' in dir(mylist)`,  is false

As I looked deeper into it,

`'__next__' in dir (mylist.__iter__())` is true

1. why is`__next__` only available to list but only to `__iter__()` and `mygen` but not `mylist`. How does `__iter__()` call `__next__` when we are stepping thru the list using list-comprehension

   Trying to manually step (+1) up the generator, I called `mygen.__next__()`. It doesn't exist. It only exist as `mygen.__next__`which is called method-wrapper.
2. what is a method-wrapper and what does it do? How is it applied here: in `mygen() and __iter__() ?`
3. if `__next__` is what both generator and iterator provide (and their sole properties) then what is the difference between generator and iterator?*

   Answer to 3: Solved, as noted by mod/editor:

   [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

UPDATE: both generator and iterator have `__next__()`. My mistake. Looking at the logs, somehow `mygen.__next__()` test was giving me stopiteration exception error. But I wasn't able to duplicate that error again.

Thanks everyone for answering!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Comment: "Trying to manually step (+1) up the generator, I called `mygen.__next__()`. It doesn't exist." - yeah it does. If it looked like it didn't, you screwed up your test.

Comment: You are right. `a=[1,2,3,4].__iter__()
a.__next__()` yielded `Out[1] 1` obviously stepping up. But the other `mygen.__next__()` are failing like so: `StopIteration                             
<snip>
---> 14 mygen.__next__()

StopIteration: ` I also overlooked this error and assumed that it was missing. But it wasn't. it was just stopIteration error. I still don't get why it would throw stopiteration exception when  `__next__()` haven't once called yet.

Comment: Ok somehow, `mygen.__next__()` is now working. it was giving me `stopiteration exception` earlier. I am not able to duplicate it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @theMobDog `__next__` will throw a StopIteration exception when the iterator reached its end. You would need to create a new iterator if you want to iterate the object again.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The special methods `__iter__` and `__next__` are part of the iterator protocol to create [iterator types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). For this purpose, you have to differentiate between two separate things: **Iterables** and **iterators**.

*Iterables* are things that can be iterated, usually, these are some kind of container elements that contain items. Common examples are lists, tuples, or dictionaries.

In order to iterate an iterable, you use an *iterator*. An iterator is the object that helps you iterate through the container. For example, when iterating a list, the iterator essentially keeps track of which index you are currently at.

To get an iterator, the `__iter__` method is called on the iterable. This is like a factory method that returns a new iterator for this specific iterable. A type having a `__iter__` method defined, turns it into an iterable.

The iterator generally needs a single method, `__next__`, which returns the *next* item for the iteration. In addition, to make the protocol easier to use, every iterator should also be an iterable, returning itself in the `__iter__` method.

As a quick example, this would be a possible iterator implementation for a list:

```
class ListIterator:
    def __init__ (self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.idx = 0

    def __iter__ (self):
        return self

    def __next__ (self):
        try:
            item = self.lst[self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.idx += 1
        return item
```

The list implementation could then simply return `ListIterator(self)` from the `__iter__` method. Of course, the actual implementation for lists is done in C, so this looks a bit different. But the idea is the same.

Iterators are used invisibly in various places in Python. For example a `for` loop:

```
for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

This is kind of the same to the following:

```
lst_iterator = iter(lst) # this just calls `lst.__iter__()`
while True:
    try:
        item = next(lst_iterator) # lst_iterator.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        print(item)
```

So the for loop requests an iterator from the iterable object, and then calls `__next__` on that iterable until it hits the `StopIteration` exception. That this happens under the surface is also the reason why you would want iterators to implement the `__iter__` as well: Otherwise you could never loop over an iterator.

---

As for generators, what people usually refer to is actually a generator *function*, i.e. some function definition that has `yield` statements. Once you call that generator function, you get back a *generator*. A generator is esentially just an iterator, albeit a fancy one (since it does more than move through a container). As an iterator, it has a `__next__` method to “generate” the next element, and a `__iter__` method to return itself.

---

An example generator function would be the following:

```
def exampleGenerator():
    yield 1
    print('After 1')
    yield 2
    print('After 2')
```

The function body containing a `yield` statement turns this into a generator function. That means that when you call `exampleGenerator()` you get back a *generator* object. Generator objects implement the iterator protocol, so we can call `__next__` on it (or use the the `next()` function as above):

```
>>> x = exampleGenerator()
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
After 1
2
>>> next(x)
After 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    next(x)
StopIteration
```

Note that the first `next()` call did not print anything yet. This is the special thing about generators: They are lazy and only evaluate as much as necessary to get the next item from the iterable. Only with the second `next()` call, we get the first printed line from the function body. And we need another `next()` call to exhaust the iterable (since there’s not another value yielded).

But apart from that laziness, generators just act like iterables. You even get a `StopIteration` exception at the end, which allows generators (and generator functions) to be used as `for` loop sources and wherever “normal” iterables can be used.

The big benefit of generators and their laziness is the ability to generate stuff *on demand*. A nice analogy for this is endless scrolling on websites: You can scroll down item after after (calling `next()` on the generator), and every once in a while, the website will have to query a backend to retrieve more items for you to scroll through. Ideally, this happens without you noticing. And that’s exactly what a generator does. It even allows for things like this:

```
def counter():
    x = 0
    while True:
        x += 1
        yield x
```

Non-lazy, this would be impossible to compute since this is an infinite loop. But lazily, as a generator, it’s possible to consume this iterative one item after an item. I originally wanted to spare you from implementing this generator as a fully custom iterator type, but in this case, this actually isn’t too difficult, so here it goes:

```
class CounterGenerator:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.x = 0

    def __iter__ (self):
        return self

    def __next__ (self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. That is quite extensive! I am reading now.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is `__next__` only available to list but only to `__iter__()` and `mygen` but not `mylist`. How does `__iter__()` call `__next__` when we are stepping through the list using list-comprehension.

Because lists have a separate object that is returned from `iter` to handle iteration, this objects `__iter__` is consecutively called.

So, for lists:

```
iter(l) is l # False, returns <list-iterator object at..>
```

While, for generators:

```
iter(g) is g # True, its the same object
```

In looping constructs, `iter` is first going to get called on the target object to be looped over. `iter` calls `__iter__` and an iterator is expected to be returned; its `__next__` is called until no more elements are available.

> What is a method-wrapper and what does it do? How is it applied here: in `mygen()` and `__iter__()`?

A method wrapper is, if I'm not mistaken, a method implemented in `C`. Which is what both these `iter(list).__iter__` (`list` is an object implemented in `C`) and `gen.__iter__` (not sure here but generators are probably too) are.

> If `__next__` is what both generator and iterator provide (and their sole properties) then what is the difference between generator and iterator?

A generator is an iterator, as is the iterator provided from `iter(l)`. It is an iterator since it provides a `__next__` method (which, usually, when used in a for loop it is capable of providing values until exhausted).

Comment: Thanks for detailed steps on `iter` calling `next`. Just to clarify, in a list comprehension `x for x in mylist` somewhere along there, `iter` object is returned and started calling `next`?

Answer (score 1):

`__next__` and `__iter__` are method wrappers for when you do `next(some_gen)` or `iter(some_sequence)`. `next(some_gen)` is the same as `some_gen.__next__()`

So if I do `mygen = iter(mylist)` then `mygen` is `mylist` implemented as a generator object and has a `__next__` method descriptor. Lists themselves do not have this method because they are not generators.

Generators are iterators. Check out [difference between generators and iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Comment: Good explaination on between mygen and mylist. and `mygen=iter(mylist)` . Thanks.