# Is there a magic and dunder method to make a list object in python OOP

Tags: python, list

For example - I have a class

```
class SimpleClass:
      def __init__(self,strings):
          pass
```

Can i add a special method to this like `__list__` or something, so that when i do this -

```
a = SimpleClass('hi')
list(a)
```

will make a list of the string but with more of my own methods. I mean that when i call `list(a)` a list will be created of the string plus with some of my extra strings to that list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) method. For example:

```py
class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self, strings):
        self.strings = strings

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.strings
        yield "something else"


a = SimpleClass("hi")
print(list(a))
```

Prints:

```
['hi', 'something else']
```

Comment: @PCM You don't have to use `yield`, but it's easiest. For example, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40255361/10035985

Comment: Similarly, what is the method for dict and set and tuple.

Comment: the same mechanism that works for `list` works for `tuple` and `set`: just like `l = list(a)` will return a `list`, so `s = set(a)` and `t=tuple(a)` will return a `set` and a `tuple` respectively. For `dict`, which result would you expect? Which keys, and which values?

Comment: Anyhow, `d = dict(zip(["key1","key2],a))` will return a `dict`