# how does the for-loop with k, v in contact_emails.items(): work?

Tags: python, for-loop

This is the screenshot of the code in question, on Chegg.com

[CheggStudy Q&A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cocen.jpg)

and this is the code itself, copypasted from Chegg.com

```
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn': 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

new_contact = input()
new_email = input()
contact_emails[new_contact] = new_email

for k, v in contact_emails.items():
    print(v, "is", k)
```

**My screen looked like this:**
[My Screen With Code Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vrDI.jpg)

...As you can see, it works flawlessly despite it missing some of the code included in the suggested answer, and I just don't know how it works in general. I was glad for the help but I did not get any more information about how and why it works! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you have omitted simply prompts for and adds a new entry to the `contact_emails` dictionary (so you have a fourth entry).

Comment: Try this visual platform next to see what's happening - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 1):

`.items()` will return a [`view`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict-views) object. This object contains a dynamic view of all your key-value pairs in the dictionary as tuples, updating as the dictionary updates. The `for` loop then calls the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function on the view, which returns an [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). The `iterator` represents all your key-value pairs as a stream of data. Again, behind the scenes, the `for` loop will grab each successive key-value pair using the [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method. The `__next__()` method returns a tuple with your key and value. Finally, you use [tuple unpacking](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp) to split this tuple into 2 different variables. Here is a bit what this code would look like behind the scenes without a for-loop.

```py
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn': 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

# you can modify your dict if you want here

# get our view of the dict
items = contact_emails.items() 

# we get our stream of key-value pairs
# the for loop will do this in the background
item_iterator = iter(items) 

try:
    # we use while True because we use an error to exit the loop
    while True:
        # we call __next__() on the iterator to get our next pair
        kv_pair = item_iterator.__next__()

        # we assign iteration variables here
        # this special syntax is called "tuple unpacking"
        # It lets us split a pair of data into 2 variables easily.
        k, v = kv_pair

        # this is what would be the body of the for-loop
        print(v, "is", k)
        # ... 

# the __next__() raises an exception to break out of the while loop.
# it can't use the break keyword because it is inside a method and doesn't know about the while loop
except StopIteration:
    # we've accomplished our goal of leaving the while loop
    # we can just ignore the error and continue moving on
    pass
```

This syntax is kind of bulky, so python will instead just perform all the magic for us inside the for-loop construct.

Here's some further reading you can do about iterators, exceptions, tuple unpacking, and for loops.

[Python iter() method - GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iter-method/)

[Iterables - Python Like You Mean It](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html)

[__next__ in generators and iterators and what is a method-wrapper? - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255096/next-in-generators-and-iterators-and-what-is-a-method-wrapper)

[Are exceptions for flow control best practice in Python? - Software Engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351110/are-exceptions-for-flow-control-best-practice-in-python)

[Unpacking a Tuple in Python - GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/)

[Loop Better: a deeper look at iteration in Python - Trey Hunner](https://treyhunner.com/2019/06/loop-better-a-deeper-look-at-iteration-in-python/)