# Difference between next and for in python 3 generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand generator in python 3. I try the following code:

```
def int_gen():
    """Infinite integer generator"""
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        yield n

print(next(int_gen())) # 2 
print(next(int_gen())) # 2
print(next(int_gen())) # 2
```

However, in this case:

```
for i in int_gen():
    print(i)
```

The results as I expected:

```
2
3
4
...
```

Refering to: [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators) and [this example](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)

Why do 2 results difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `int_gen()`, you make a new generator that restarts everything. If you want the generator to continue where it left off, you'll have to save it so you have something useful to pass to `next()`.

```
it = int_gen()
print(next(it)) # 2
print(next(it)) # 3
print(next(it)) # 4
```