# Why read the column of a csv file twice and the last column is None?

Tags: python, csv

My code is below:

```
file  = open('traintag1.csv', 'r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
data = [x[-1] for x in csv_reader]
print len(data)
target = [x[-2] for x in csv_reader]
print len(target)
```

and the result is `len(data)=430` which is right but `len(target)=0` which is supposed to be `430` the same as `len(data)`. Why are the lengths different?

Also, is there any way to read a csvfile by column?

The file contains data like this:

```
7765,1256,http://hshihwih.com,0
12453,18978,http://shjhjkshd.com,1
```

Comment: Give us a sample from 'traintag1.csv'. It's impossible to tell without a data.

Comment: `data = [row[col_num] for row in csv_reader]` will read all the data in column number `col_num` into a list named `data`.

Comment: I do not quite understand. Can you just give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: The reason is csv_reader is an iterable which can be iterated for single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue :**

You are facing this problem since `csv_reader` is [ITERATOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators) (Please google this concept :) ).

Iterator is object which has "`next`" method available. When you execute `csv_reader = csv.reader(file)` , it creates `csv_reader` as iterator. `csv_reader.next()` will give you one line at the time. But as the lines are over, there is no way to restart it again.

Please check below :

```
C:\Users\dinesh\Desktop>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (
AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> file  = open('a.csv','r')
>>> csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
>>>
>>> dir(csv_reader)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__has
h__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr_
_', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'dialect', 'line
_num', 'next']
>>>
>>> csv_reader.next()
['7765', '1256', 'http://hshihwih.com', '0']
>>>
>>> csv_reader.next()
['12453', '18978', 'http://shjhjkshd.com', '1']
>>>
>>> csv_reader.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

In your code, when first iterations are done for `data` is done, again it can't come back for `target` due to reason I explained aboved.

**Solution :**

Collect data in one loop as below :

```
import csv

file  = open('a.csv','r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
data = []
target = []
for x in csv_reader:
    data.append(x[-1])
    target.append(x[-2])

print data
print len(data)
print target
print len(target)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
file  = open('traintag1.csv','r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
data, target = zip(*[(x[-1], x[-2]) for x in csv_reader])
print len(data)
print len(target)
```

This code creates a list of tuples, and then uses zip to expand the pairs into independent lists.

Answer (score 1):

`csv_reader` is iterate once object. If you iterate it one time you cannot iterate it next time, so you won't get any values for second loop.

Please try this simple code,

```
import csv

file  = open('traintag1.csv','r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

target = []
data = []
for x in csv_reader:
    data.append(x[-1])
    target.append(x[-2])

print len(data)
print len(target)
```

In this code both values of `target` and `data` were fetched from a single loop.

Please let me know in terms of any queries.