# Why does this code execute wrong?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

There is an input file "input.txt". It looks like:

```
7
4
2
5
2
9
8
6
10
8
4
```

And there's a code:

```
inn = open("/storage/emulated/0/input.txt", "r")
a = 0
b = 10
array = []

while not a == b:
     for i, line in enumerate(inn):
         if i == a:
              array += str(line)
     a+=1
print(array)
```

I need to put all the numbers in "array" variable, but wher I run the code -- I get empty "array". Is there a mistake in a code?

(sorry for such noob question)

Comment: you're not modifying `array` at all ...

Comment: How about putting a print inside your `if` block too see if it is actually being executed?

Comment: Just use `array = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=int)` to read those values to the variable `array`.

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting idea...

Comment: Oh, now code adds only '4' in array, but I need full "input.txt." file add to "array" variable.

Comment: @Michael now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Did you replace `filename` with `"/storage/emulated/0/input.txt"`? "now it doesn't work at all" means that there is an error message right? Do you mind showing that?

Comment: @Michael yes I did. I replaced "filename" with the path to input file. And code shows me TypeError (TypeError: must be str or None, not bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. Also, I don't get an empty array when running your code. See the following code and the results. I still suggest using `np.genfromtxt` when the input data is as clean as yours.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

# I have input.txt in same directory as this .py-file

# np.genfromtxt with int and with string
approach1a = np.genfromtxt('input.txt', dtype=int)
approach1b = np.genfromtxt('input.txt', dtype=np.str_)

# list comprehension
approach2 = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
    approach2 = [str(line) for line in file]

# like your approach, but without a, b and the if statement
approach3 = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        approach3.append(line)

# your code
inn = open("input.txt", "r")
a = 0
b = 10
array = []
while not a == b:
    for i, line in enumerate(inn):
        if i == a:
            array += str(line)
    a+=1
```

Results:

```
>>> approach1a
array([ 7,  4,  2,  5,  2,  9,  8,  6, 10,  8,  4])
>>> approach1b
array(['7', '4', '2', '5', '2', '9', '8', '6', '10', '8', '4'],
      dtype='<U2')
>>> approach2
['7\n', '4\n', '2\n', '5\n', '2\n', '9\n', '8\n', '6\n', '10\n', '8\n', '4']
>>> approach3
['7\n', '4\n', '2\n', '5\n', '2\n', '9\n', '8\n', '6\n', '10\n', '8\n', '4']
>>> array
['7', '\n']
```

The reason that only the first line of the inpur file is read with your code is because with `open` you can only iterate over the lines *once*. If you have done that, you can't go back. To understand that, see for example @Aaron Hall's anwer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators): there is only a method `next`, but there is no way to go back (in this case to go back a line). You have reached that point where all lines of `open` were used once when you set the value of `a` to `1`, i.e. after you have added the first line of the input file to `array`. This is why I understand that your code only reads the first line, why I can't reproduce you claiming you have `array` as an empty list and why I suggested `approach3`.