# Explain: Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, generator

I know what iterators and generators are. I know the iteration protocol, and I can create both. I read the following line everywhere: "Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa." I understand the first part, but I don't understand the "not vice versa" part. What does the generator object have that any simple iterator object does not?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators) but it does not explain why an iterator is not a generator. Is it just the syntax `yield` that explains the difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators?rq=1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Comment: A generator specifically generates its values using `yield`. That is not true of all iterators.

Comment: @RichardNeumann think he has read that post and wants expansion on the first answer...

Comment: @RichardNeumann https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators does not answer my question

Comment: @EdChum yes, I read many and the one you mentioned

Comment: "What does the genrator object has that any simple iterator object does not?" Being an instance of `generator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know what's iterator, what's generator, what's iteration protocol, how to create both.

### What's an iterator?

Per the glossary, an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-iterator) is "an object representing a stream of data".  It has an *__iter__()* method returns itself, and it has a *next()* method (which is *__next__()* in Python 3).  The next-method is responsible for returning a value, advancing the iterator, and raising *StopIteration* when done.

### What is a generator?

A generator is a regular Python function containing `yield`.  When called it returns a generator-iterator (one of the many kinds of iterator).

### Examples of how to create generators and iterators

**Generator example:**

```
>>> def f(x):           # "f" is a generator
        yield x
        yield x**2
        yield x**3

>>> g = f(10)           # calling "f" returns a generator-iterator 
>>> type(f)             # "f" is a regular python function with "yield"
<type 'function'>
>>> type(g)                 
<type 'generator'>
>>> next(g)             # next() gets a value from the generator-iterator
10
>>> next(g)
100
>>> next(g)
1000
>>> next(g)             # iterators signal that they are done with an Exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
StopIteration
>>> dir(g)              # generator-iterators have next() and \__iter__
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'gi_code', 'gi_frame', 'gi_running', 'next', 'send', 'throw']
```

**Iterator using a class:**

```
>>> class Powers:       # "Powers" is a class
        def __init__(self, base):
            self.base = base
            self.exp = 0
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def next(self):
            self.exp += 1
            if self.exp > 3:
                raise StopIteration
            return self.base ** self.exp

>>> g = Powers(10)      # calling "Powers" returns an iterator
>>> type(Powers)        # "Power" is a regular python class
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(g)             # "g" is a iterator instance with next() and __iter__()
<type 'instance'>   
>>> next(g)             # next() gets a value from the iterator
10
>>> next(g)
100
>>> next(g)
1000
>>> next(g)             # iterators signal that they are done with an Exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
StopIteration
```

### Iterator from a sequence example:

```
>>> s = 'cat'               
>>> it = iter(s)            # creates an "iterator" from a sequence 
>>> type(s)                 # "s" is a string which is "iterable"
<type 'str'>
>>> type(it)                # An "iterator" with next() and __iter__()
<type 'iterator'>
>>> next(it)
'c'
>>> next(it)
'a'
>>> next(it)
't'
>>> next(it)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    next(it)
StopIteration
```

### Comparison and conclusion

An iterator is an object representing a stream of data.  It has an *__iter__()* method and a *next()* method.

There are several ways to make an iterator:

1) Call a generator (a regular python function that uses `yield`)
2) Instantiate a class that has an *__iter__()* method and a *next()* method.

**From this, you can see that a generator is just one of many ways to make an iterator** (there are other ways as well:  itertools, iter() on a regular function and a sentinel, etc).

Comment: one can send(value) to generators but not iterators. every call to iterator returns or raise while generators can 'return a value via yield multiple times for once entering

Comment: That is a red-herring.  An iterator class could easily add a *send()* method if desired.   Also, generators and iterators both existing before we extended their capabilities with *send()*.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger So the difference between iterators and generators is in the way that they are constructed? Like getting the same burger (has both `__iter__` and `__next__`) from McDonalds (iterator) and McDrive (generator)? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In python3 an iterator is an object with a `__next__` method. That's all.

For an object to be a generator it needs  `__next__` method but it also use a yield statement.

So both object have a `__next__` method and so are iterator but the first object doesn't always have a yield statement so an iterator is not necessarily a generator.

In fact it means that when you generate a generator all its code is **not** run at once. Meanwhile with a more classical iterator you will run only once the generation code.

Answer (score -1):

It's just that generators are a specific kind of iterators.
Their two particular traits are the lazy evaluation (no value is computed in anticipation of it being requested), and the fact that once exhausted, they cannot be iterated once again.

On the other hand, an iterator is no more than something with a `__next__` method, and an `__iter__` method.

So lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries... are iterators.
But those are not generators, because all of the elements they contain are defined and evaluated after the container initialization, and they can be iterated over many times.

Therefore, some iterators are not generators.

Comment: lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries are iterables or containers not iterators I think.

Comment: I would say lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries are iterables, but are iterated over by iterators. They aren't iterators themselves.