# Python zip object can be used only once. Why is that?

Tags: python, iterator

I wanted to learn the functionalities of the zip class. I wrote this very simple example.

```
>>> names = ['name1','name2','name3']
>>> ages = ['age1','age2','age3']
>>> print(zip(names, ages))
<zip object at 0x03DB18F0>
>>> zipped = zip(names, ages)
for i in zipped:
    type(i)
    print(i)
```

and the output is (as expected) -

```
<class 'tuple'>
('name1', 'age1')
<class 'tuple'>
('name2', 'age2')
<class 'tuple'>
('name3', 'age3')
```

However immediately after this line if i write:

```
for i in zipped:
    print(i)
```

it compiles but prints nothing!

To recheck I did this again -

```
>>> zipped = zip(names, ages)
>>> for i in zipped:
    print(i)
('name1', 'age1')
('name2', 'age2')
('name3', 'age3')
```

This time it prints correctly. But while doing unzip -

```
>>> names2, ages2 = zip(*zipped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    names2, ages2 = zip(*zipped)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

It seems the `zipped` variable becomes empty for some reason?

> Note: if required you may change the title of the question. I am using python 3.6.1 on a windows (10) machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`zip` produces an *iterator* (`<zip object at 0x03DB18F0>`) which can only be iterated once. Once you have iterated it, it's exhausted. If you want to produce a *list* which can be iterated as often as you like:

```
zipped = list(zip(names, ages))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. that was the only guess that I was having :) it sounds like how a generator works. is it same/similar implementation?

Comment: @Arjee generators are a language construct that was introduced to make writing iterators easier, but not all iterators are generators, and now generators have been used for other things, as co-routines for example.

Comment: @Arjee see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators) question.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `zip` returns an `iterator` object. They can't be iterated more than once, then they become *exhausted*.

You can create a *list* out of your iterator using `list(zip(names, ages))`.

The `list` uses the iterator object to create a list, which can be iterated multiple times.

You can read more about the [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) function here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for noting that, I've correct my answer