# Iterators vs Generators vs Iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, iterator, generator

I am newbie to `Python`. I was able to understand `Iterables` and `Iterators`.
However I have seen that there is lot of stuff that compares `Generators` vs `Iterators`.

As per understanding, `Iterable` is an object which actually has elements stored inside it (E.g. a list). They follow an iteration protocol where they implement `__iter__()` method which returns an `Iterator` object which helps in iterating the `Iterable`.

As per my understanding `Generators` helps in generating the data on the fly instead of creating a big data structure in memory and returning it. We can achieve simialr goal by the use of `Iterators` as well.

Now my doubt, If we already had `Iterators` what was the need of `Generators`, since both helps acheiving a similar goal of generating data on the fly.
Is that just to simplify the syntax or is there any other reason why `Generators` exist ?

Comment: Generators are iterators, they are just a simplified version of an iterator that uses the `yield` syntax, but they have less functionalities. This post covers everything you need to know, possibly a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776829/6622817

Comment: A generator is technically an iterator, basically, it's a way to define iterator protocol in a compact way. A classic iterator will be defined using a class with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods, with a generator you can do this with just a function with yield statements or generator expressions.

Comment: So generators exists just to simplify the syntax or is there any othere reason ?

Comment: That's it! Just simplifies things so it's easier to read.

Comment: An _iterable_ is anything you can iterate over.

Comment: I think [Aaron Hall♦'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353158/4014959) at the linked question covers everything nicely.

Comment: https://noobknowledge.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 21):

Here's how these terms are defined in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) in the official Python documentation.

**iterable**

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of
>   iterables include all sequence types (such as `list`, `str`, and
>   `tuple`) and some non-sequence types like `dict`, `file` objects, and
>   objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` method or with
>   a `__getitem__()` method that implements Sequence semantics.
>
> Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a
>   sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, …). When an iterable object is
>   passed as an argument to the built-in function `iter()`, it returns an
>   iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass over the
>   set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not necessary to
>   call `iter()` or deal with iterator objects yourself. The `for`
>   statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary
>   unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop.
>   See also iterator, sequence, and generator.

**iterator**

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the
>   iterator’s `__next__()` method (or passing it to the built-in function
>   `next()`) return successive items in the stream. When no more data are
>   available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. At this
>   point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its
>   `__next__()` method just raise `StopIteration` again. Iterators are
>   required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator
>   object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in
>   most places where other iterables are accepted. One notable exception
>   is code which attempts multiple iteration passes. A container object
>   (such as a `list`) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it
>   to the `iter()` function or use it in a for loop. Attempting this with
>   an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used
>   in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty
>   container.
>
> More information can be found in Iterator Types.

**generator**

> A function which returns a generator iterator. It looks like a normal
>   function except that it contains `yield` expressions for producing a
>   series of values usable in a `for`-loop or that can be retrieved one
>   at a time with the `next()` function.
>
> Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator
>   iterator in some contexts. In cases where the intended meaning isn’t
>   clear, using the full terms avoids ambiguity.

**generator iterator**

> An object created by a generator function.
>
> Each `yield` temporarily suspends processing, remembering the location
>   execution state (including local variables and pending
>   `try`-statements). When the generator iterator resumes, it picks-up
>   where it left-off (in contrast to functions which start fresh on every
>   invocation).