# Nested for loop over range()

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following code:

```
x = range(10)
for i in x:
    print(i)
    for j in x:
        print(">> %d" % j)
        break
```

I would have expected the output to be:

```
0 
>> 1
2
>> 3
..
```

but instead, it is:

```
0
>> 0
1
>> 0
2
>> 0
..
```

Why does range behave in this way?

Comment: You are breaking out of the inner loop, so `j` starts at 0 each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By converting `x` to an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), you can achieve your expected behavior.

```
x = iter(range(10))

for i in x:
    print(i)
    for j in x:
        print('> {}'.format(j))
        break
```

which returns

```
0
> 1
2
> 3
4
> 5
6
> 7
8
> 9
```

What this shows us is that the problem does not lie with the `break`ing out of the inner loop per say but rather with `range` not being depleted as you loop over it. This happens because `range` **is not an iterator** and thus it restarts every time instead of picking up from where it left off.

Comment: So, given that `range` is iterable, but not an iterator, does that mean that each `for` loop creates an iterator from it implicitly?

Comment: An iterator is **not** implicitly created; you cannot call `next()` on a `range()` object. It is simply an iterable.

Comment: @lumisota Take a look at this [in depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353158/6162307). It is a nice read.

Answer (score 2):

```
for j in x:
        print(">> %d" % j)
        break
```

You are breaking the loop of J causing the value of J to reset and go back to 0 everytime.