# why do we need python generator when iter() has next() sub function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand the concept of the Iterator and Generator in Python. But I have below queries:

When I use a generator I get a value one at a time, however according to the iterator concept it  gives the output as a whole. So why does the iter() function has next() sub function? for example

```
rt = "default"
>>> type(iter(rt))
<type 'iterator'>
>>> iter(rt).next()
'd'
```

So, when we do a iter().next() we are getting single output at a time, so how it is different from generator?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you asking what is difference between a generator and an iterator?

Comment: An iterator is an object that yields items one at a time. A generator *returns* an object that acts as an iterator. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @TomZych, I guess you are saying the other way around. The generator yields an object one at a time not the iterator. Anyway, what I meant was from my example I have one object at a time through iterator, and the same feature is present in generator as well. So apart from memory advantage  I do not see a reason why should I use Generator over iterator. I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami I am not asking difference between Generator and Iterator.

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re asking, but you don’t seem to be very clear on the relationship between iterators and generators. You may find these docs useful; see the sections “Iterators” and “Generators”. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html

Comment: Then what do you mean bt "it" in "how it is different from generator?"