# Why am i getting the valueerror?

Tags: python

```
l=['Python', 3, 2, 4, 5, 'version']
l=filter(lambda x:type(x)==int,l)
print(list(l))
print(max(l))
```

getting this error but i don't know why..
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

if I am not printing list(l) it will work..

```
l=['Python', 3, 2, 4, 5, 'version']
l=filter(lambda x:type(x)==int,l)
print(max(l))
```

output: 5

after printing the list of the filter object it won't work and i don't know why can you help me?
any fix?

Comment: I'd assume that `list(l)` consumes the sequence, leaving `l` as an iterator past the end of the sequence

Comment: In Python 2, `filter` was a function that returned a list. In Python 3, it is a class whose instances are iterators.

Answer (score 6):

`filter` returns an iterator. After calling `list(l)`, the iterator is exhausted, and thus you can't draw any more values from it.

You can try this and see:

```py
l = ['Python', 3, 2, 4, 5, 'version']
l = filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, l)
print(list(l))
print(list(l))
```

And the second print statement gives the empty list:

```
[3, 2, 4, 5]
[]
```

This would work:

```py
l = ['Python', 3, 2, 4, 5, 'version']
l = filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, l)
l = list(l)
print(l)
print(max(l))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators

Comment: Thanks @chepner for the edit! I definitely missed that.

Comment: `generator` is a specific class, instances of which are defined using generator expressions  or generator functions. Iterator is the term for anything that implements `__next__`, allowing you to retrieve an argument via the `next` function. As far as I know, you could use "generator" as a synonym for "iterator", but I think it's clearer to avoid the ambiguity.