# Empty list when using "reversed" iterator a second time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is the second print command giving an empty list while the first is giving proper output?

```
str1 = 'Hello'

str2 = reversed(str1)

print(list(str2))
print(list(str2))
```

Output:

```
['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'H']
[]
```

Comment: Related: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738468/why-am-i-getting-the-valueerror/65738510#65738510) from just 2 days ago -- though in that case it was `filter` (same principle though).

Answer (score 4):

**reversed** is an iterator, iterators can be consumed only once meaning once you iterate over them, you cannot do it again.

[Check the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause for `[]` (empty [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list))

The built-in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), is an iterator, so it get *exhausted* once you have *consumed* it, by making a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). In your case, once you make it a do, `list(revered("Hello"))`, it becomes, *exhausted*.

#### Solution

A quick solution could be making another iterator, code:

```
str1 = "Hello" # Original String 

iter1 = reversed(str1) # Making the first iterator 
iter2 = reversed(str1) # Making the second iterator 

print(list(iter1), list(iter2)) # Printing the iterator once they are lists
```

Comment: The more common solution is to turn the iterator to a list: `str2 = list(reversed(str1))`

Comment: It seems wasteful to call `reversed` twice. You almost always want to re-use the reversed list (perhaps multiple times) in the code, so its worth calling `list` to convert it immediately.