# dask dataframe: generator from partitions

Tags: python, pandas, generator, dask, dask-dataframe

I wonder if it's possible to turn `dask` objects into generators. Specifically, can the following `pandas`-based generator be replicated using `dask` dataframe, turning each partition into a generator:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['a'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

def gen_pandas(df):
# this is a sample function, its content is not
# important as long as it yields values
    for d in df.iterrows():
        yield d

g = gen_pandas(df)
next(g), next(g)
```

As another example (not specific to dask dataframes), suppose I wanted to have generators on workers, such that each worker reads a file and returns contents line by line (just as an example function).

Apologies if the question doesn't make sense or is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming you mean *iterator* here, not generator (see [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)).

So, you can use `iterrows` on a dask DataFrame, but you shouldn't, because it'll be very slow and inefficient. (Also as a sidenote, [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) is [usually preferred](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43874) over [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).)

[Dask's `iterrows` method](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/dd636df4ba5e3bc63bd0f86e5a344966864d4539/dask/dataframe/core.py#L4784-L4788) has to compute each partition, then iterate over its rows, which eliminates a lot of the benefits of Dask. But your `gen_pandas` function will behave the same on `ddf` as on `df`. (You also don't need the function at all; `gen_pandas(df)` is exactly the same as just `df.iterrows()`)

> turning each partition into a generator

If you meant that you want to iterate over *partitions*, not rows, then you can use `ddf.partitions` to access each partition as its own dask DataFrame:

```
>>> list(ddf.partitions)
[Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    a
 npartitions=1       
 0              int64
 4                ...
 Dask Name: blocks, 4 tasks,
 Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    a
 npartitions=1       
 4              int64
 8                ...
 Dask Name: blocks, 4 tasks,
 Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    a
 npartitions=1       
 8              int64
 9                ...
 Dask Name: blocks, 4 tasks]
```

However, in either case, you should consider not trying to iterate over a dask DataFrame. Instead, try mapping your operation using [`apply`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply) or [`map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions). This will allow dask to run the operation in parallel over every partition at once.

For example, instead of:

```
ids = []
counts = []
for row in ddf.iterrows():
    page = download_wikipedia_page(row.wikipedia_name)
    link_count = count_num_links(page)
    ids.append(row.id)
    results.append(link_count)
counts = pd.Series(counts, ids)
```

You'd do this with Dask:

```
def get_wikipedia_page_count(row: pd.Series) -> int:
    page = download_wikipedia_page(row.wikipedia_name)
    return count_num_links(page)

counts = ddf.apply(get_wikipedia_page_count, axis=1, meta=int)
```

Iterators are fundamentally serial. Dask is fundamentally parallel. By forcing Dask to operate serially, you lose a lot of the benefits of Dask. To get good performance, you'll need to refactor iterator-based code to map that operation over every partition in parallel.

Alternatively, if the iterator approach makes more sense for your code, you might be interested in the [streamz](https://streamz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, which is for making streaming pipelines and integrates with Dask.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am specifically interested in generators: `gen_pandas` is only an example function and its content is not important (for the question) as long as it has a yield statement.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev can you clarify your question then? "turn `dask` objects into generators" doesn't really make sense—you can never turn any Python object into a generator function. Instead, are you trying to write a generator function which _iterates_ through the dask object in some way? I think my answer will help you do that (though as I've said, you should also ideally just not do that).

Comment: Or I wonder if [streaming results back from dask](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/4754) is something you're interested in?

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I might be wrong in phrasing this, but isn't it possible to turn say a string into a generator (e.g. some sort of char-by-char processing)? The streaming link is also interesting, let me update the question with another example.

Comment: You don't "turn a string into a generator"; you'd turn a string into a _iterator_, or _iterate_ over a string. (See [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators) that I linked.) You could write a generator function that iterates over something internally, but the key part is still iteration.

If you're trying to _iterate_ over the contents of a Dask DataFrame then this answer applies, for both how to do it and why you shouldn't do it.