# How come this sum() syntax right in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this simple code snippet from somewhere, but I don't understand how come this sum() syntax works.

```
total = sum(1 for _ in [1,2,3,4,5])
print(total)      # 5
```

`for _ in [1,2,3,4,5]` is nothing but the looping five times.

So the code snippet loops five times and add 1 for each loop so becomes 5 I guess.

I'm not sure about while looping five times in `for _ in [1,2,3,4,5]` what's happening then with 1?

According to the syntax of sum(iterable, start), the first argument should be iterable, but 1 is int. How come this works based on the sum syntax.
How this code internally works?
I'm confused.

Comment: The entire statement `1 for _ in [1,2,3,4,5]` is the iterator. Remember, arguments are separated by commas `,` so you can tell that everything between the parentheses is a single argument. (The commas in the list literal don't count)

Comment: The values from the list are ignored, only its length serves the purpose, as it ensures there are 5 iterations. In each iteration you yield the value 1. You could also do it with `sum(1 for _ in "aaaaa")`, because only the length of the string is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

`1 for _ in [1,2,3,4,5]` is an iterator which is similar to

```
def my_gen():
    for _ in range(5):
        yield 1
```

This returns `1` five times. So the line can be written as

```
sum((1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! This is called generator expression ( just googled it ). Learned a new thing.

Comment: YW. A generator is a type of iterator. Read more about it here: [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353158)

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you break it down:

```py
(1 for _ in [1,2,3])
```

or even

```py
[1 for _ in [1,2,3]]
```

works as counting the elements of the list. So providing the iterable the result of that expression (`[1,1,1]`) to the `sum()` is providing the expected result.