# Generic writer/outputter. What Reader is to Iterator, what is Writer to X?

Tags: java, iterator, guava

In Java the abstract version of a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) that works with **pulling** Objects (instead of characters) is an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

The question is there an abstract version of `Appendable` or [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) where I can **push** objects (ie an interface)?

In the past I just make my own interface like:

```
public interface Pusher<T> {
    public void push(T o);
}
```

Is there a generic interface that is available in most environments that someone knows about that makes sense so I don't have to keep creating the above interface?

**Update:**

Here is an example of where it would be useful:

```
public void findBadCategories(final Appendable a)  {
    String q = sql.getSql("product-category-bad");
    jdbcTemplate.query(q, new RowCallbackHandler() {
        @Override
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            String id = rs.getString("product_category_id");
            String name = rs.getString("category_name");
            if (! categoryMap.containsKey(id)) {
                try {
                    a.append(id + "\t" + name + "\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using an `Appendable` here but I would much rather have my `Pusher` callback. Believe me once [Java 8 comes out I would just use closure but that closure still needs an interface](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html).

Finally the other option I have chosen before is to completely violate Guava's [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) or `Function` (although that seems even worse). Its violation of the contract because these aim to be idempotent (although I suppose if you return `true` all the time... ).

What Guava does provide though is sort of analagous to Python's generators thanks to its [AbstractIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.html).

I added an [enhancement issue to Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1129) but I agree with them that its not really their job to add something fundamental like that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html is only for CharSequences.

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). That said, I don't think the analogy between a `Reader` and an `Iterator` that you see is all that meaningful. The reason why the IO subsystem has such low-level interfaces available probably isn't information hiding; instead, I'd say they're exposing the native low-level APIs to enable writing high-performance custom IO code (for databases or network servers) without the overhead of buffering.

Comment: Ahh duh I know that :) I'm saying I want one for objects.

Comment: (Alternately, because whoever designed the IO API was on an architectural binge. Python seems to make do with a single IO abstraction just fine.)

Comment: @millimoose let me give you an example where its useful. Pulling from a giant resultset from a database you want the client to provide away to deal with the stream of objects coming in.

Comment: @millimoose because of ducktyping? I know python has generators but I am not aware of some non IO push abstraction for python either.

Comment: An interface with an `onResultSet(ResultSet)` method?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't want the client to know about ResultSet.

Comment: @AdamGent I was comparing IO APIs. Java has a huge hierarchy of classes that wrap each other to provide various layers of processing, Python only has "file objects" that support buffered, unbuffered, byte-wise and character-wise modes of operation.

Comment: @AdamGent I think you're stuck to making your own interface here. Personally I'd just tie it to its purpose, and name it something like `QueryResultHandler<TEntity>`

Comment: @millimoose Maybe Java 8 with its closures it will become more of an issue... yeah right :)

Comment: @AdamGent Java 8's lambdas would still require a SAM type as a formal method argument. However, seeing as the design is (unsurprisingly) being lifted from C#, there might be some generic lambdas available in the JDK in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I decided to do (and I think its the best option out of what others gave :P ).

I'm going to **backport Java 8's Lambda classes** (`java.util.functions.*`). Particularly this one:

```
/**
 * Performs operations upon an input object which may modify that object and/or
 * external state (other objects).
 *
 * <p>All block implementations are expected to:
 * <ul>
 * <li>When used for aggregate operations upon many elements blocks
 * should not assume that the {@code apply} operation will be called upon
 * elements in any specific order.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param <T> The type of input objects to {@code apply}.
 */
public interface Block<T> {
/**
 * Performs operations upon the provided object which may modify that object
 * and/or external state.
 *
 * @param t an input object
 */
void apply(T t);

// Some extension methods that I'll have to do with below.
}
```

Basically I'll make a new namespace like `com.snaphop.backport.java.util.functions.*` and move over the interfaces and make them work with Guava. Obviously I won't have the lambda syntax or the extension methods but those I can work around. Then in theory when Java 8 comes out it all I would have to do is a namespace switch.

Answer (score 3):

On several projects now, I've defined for this purpose what I call a *sink*:

```
interface Sink<T> {
  void put(T contribution);
}
```

With that, methods that produce objects of type `T` would demand a parameter of type `Sink<? super T>`.

Several design questions arise:

- As declared, `Sink#put()` throws no checked exceptions. That doesn't play well with I/O operations that usually throw `IOException`. To address this, you can add a type parameter that extends `Exception` and advertise that `put()` throws this type, but at that point, if you know that much about the nature of value consumption, you're probably better off defining a custom interface for it.
- As declared, `Sink#put()` does not return a value. It's not possible to indicate to the caller whether the value was accepted or not.
- With a generic interface like this, you're forced to box contributions of primitive types like `int` and `char`, which also means they can be null. Consider annotating the `contribution` parameter with `@NonNull`.

To go along with this type, related to the *generator* concept that Petr Pudlák mentions in his answer, I've defined a *source* interface:

```
interface Source<T> {
  T get();
}
```

Methods looking to draw items of type `T` from such a source demand a parameter of type `Source<? extends T>`.

For coordination with channels among concurrent processes, I've defined both `Sink#put()` and `Source#get()` to throw `InterruptedException`:

```
interface Sink<T> {
  void put(T contribution) throws InterruptedException;
}


interface Source<T> {
  T get() throws InterruptedException;
}
```

These are analogous to [Doug Lea's original](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html) [`Puttable`](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/Puttable.java) and [`Takable`](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/Takable.java) interfaces that didn't make it into the `java.util.concurrent` package, though lacking in an equivalent to the timed wait `Puttable#offer()` and `Takable#poll()` methods.

All sorts of implementations then arise that can be composed easily, such as exchangers, filters, and transformers.

Beyond my own library, I've seen the Guava library provide the [`PrimitiveSink`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/PrimitiveSink.java) and [`Funnel`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Funnel.java) types for [hashing-related purposes](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained). You may find those to be useful abstractions as well.

Comment: I like the `InterruptedException` idea. If you look at the example [interface I posted to Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1129). I had proposed the idea of an `#isAccepting()` method but was only to be consistent with `Iterator`. But I like your method better. As for the `generators` which I was a big fan of when Python came out with I just subclass Guava's AbstractIterator but only because so many things work with `Iterator`.

Comment: Also I would call the interfaces `Consumer` (Sink) and `Producer` (Source).

Comment: I eschewed the words "consumer" and "producer" because I framed the interfaces from the perspective of their callers: a caller doesn't know whether something is being produced or exposed, per se; he only knows that he has a source from which to get things. Likewise, he doesn't know whether something is consuming his contributions; he only knows that there's a place to drop them.

Comment: I forgot to mention this about the `Source` interface with respect to `Iterator`: an `Iterator` is not safe for use by more than one consuming thread, due to the *check-then-act* danger of the split `hasNext()` and `next()` methods. I deliberately framed `Source` as an abstraction of the head of a queue. Any number of threads can request items concurrently, and that request either succeeds by delivering a valid item, or "fails" by way of delivering a prearranged invalid sentinel item. For a finite sequence of items, a `Source`'s codomain must be one value larger than its underlying range.

Comment: Well I suppose one could get into a semantic debate but my feeling is methods like `get()` already have some connotation and arguably canonical behavior of returning mostly the same thing on multiple calls (ie getter). I believe there is an abstract idea that these interfaces are used for stream like behavior... ie `put` and `get` are for containers. Maybe `Source` could be `Faucet` for fun :)

Comment: I just saw your recent comment... in that case `Source` in your mind is more like Data flow variable (see Mozart programming language) or a more abstract `SynchronousQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several views on the subject:

1. The dual of an iterator is a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_science)). Iterators "consume" values from a collection, generator "provide" them. But generators are a bit different than writers. For a writer, you decide when you push an element into it. On the other hand, generators provide you with a sequence of values, one by one. Java doesn't have any specific language support for generators. See also [What is the difference between an Iterator and a Generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-iterator-and-a-generator)
2. The opposite to iterators is something you could push values into. I don't think Java has any abstraction for that. The closes I have seen is Scala's [Growable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Growable) (neglecting the `clear()` method).

Comment: @PeterPudlak I get around Java's not having generators by using Guava's [AbstractIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.html). BTW I know the difference between a writer, generator, and collections. So #1 is nice review for others its almost insulting to me.

Comment: @AdamGent Sorry, I didn't mean anything like that, you didn't mention that you know generators in your question.

Comment: Its no problem. I think you saw the post before my edits. I do love Python's generators.

Answer (score 0):

The closest is [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) but it isn't used so much.

```
public update(Observable o, Object arg)
```

I would not use Iterable instead of Reader and I would create a consumer of your choice.

A common pattern is to not use an interface but rather an annotation.

e.g.

```
@Subscriber
public void onUpdate(Update update) { }

@Subscriber
public void onInsert(Insert insert) { }

@Subscriber
public void onDelete(Delete delete) { }
```

When this class is added as a listener it subscribes to `Update`, `Insert` and `Delete` objects, and ignores any others.  This allows one object to subscribe to different type of message in a Type safe way.

Comment: Yes I use Guava's event system all the time for something similar but its rather for a long running system and not a throw away object like writer or reader is.