# What's difference between findall() and iterfind() of xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I write a program using just like below

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ET

xmlroot = ET.fromstring([my xml content])

for element in xmlroot.iterfind(".//mytag"):
    do some thing
```

it works fine on my python (v2.7.1), but after I copy it to another computer installed with python v2.6.x, `iterfind()` is not supported, on [python document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html),  below description listed

> **findall(match)**
>
> Finds all matching subelements, by tag name or path. Returns a list containing all matching elements in document order.
>
> **iterfind(match)**
>
> Finds all matching subelements, by tag name or path. Returns an iterable yielding all matching elements in document order.
>
> New in version 2.7.

my question is: these 2 function is same or not? what's difference between these two functions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like indicated in the docs -

1. **findall** returns the complete list of elements matching the `match` xpath , we can use subscripts to access them , example -

   ```
   >>> root = ET.fromstring("<a><b>c</b></a>")
   >>> root.findall("./b")
   [<Element 'b' at 0x02048C90>]
   >>> lst = root.findall("./b")
   >>> lst[0]
   <Element 'b' at 0x02048C90>
   ```

We can also use for loop to iterate through the list.

2. **iterfind** returns an iterator (generator), it does not return the list , in this case we cannot use subscripts to access the element, we can only use it in places where iterators are accepted, an example would be in a for loop.

iterfind would be faster than findall in cases where you actually want to iterate through the returned list(which is most of the time from my experience) , since findall has to create the complete list before returning, whereas iterfind finds (yields) the next element that matches the `match` only on iterating and call to `next(iter)` (which is what is internally called when iterating through the list using `for` or such constructs).

In cases where you want the list, Both seem to have similar timing.

Performance test for both cases -

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: x = ET.fromstring('<a><b>c</b><b>d</b><b>e</b></a>')

In [3]: def foo(root):
   ...:     d = root.findall('./b')
   ...:     for  y in d:
   ...:         pass
   ...: 

In [4]: def foo1(root):
   ...:     d = root.iterfind('./b')
   ...:     for y in d:
   ...:         pass
   ...: 

In [5]: %timeit foo(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.24 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit foo1(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.65 µs per loop

In [7]: def foo2(root):
   ...:     return root.findall('./b')
   ...: 

In [8]: def foo3(root):
   ...:     return list(root.iterfind('./b'))
   ...: 

In [9]: %timeit foo2(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.54 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit foo3(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: In fact, `findall(...)` is implemented using `list(iterfind(...))`. (At least in Python 3.5)

Answer (score 5):

If you do

```
for element in xmlroot.iterfind(".//mytag"):
    do some thing
```

then the elements will be retrieved from the XML file one at a time (one element per loop).

If you do

```
for element in xmlroot.findall(".//mytag"):
    do some thing
```

all the elements will be retrieved at once and stored into a (temporary) list. Only then will the `for` loop start to iterate over that list.

This means that the second method takes longer at the start (because it has to build that list) and uses more memory (same reason). Also, if you need to exit the `for` loop before you've reached the last element, you will have done unnecessary work. On the other side, once you're inside the `for` loop, the second method will probably be somewhat faster. Usually, the benefits of the first method ("lazy evaluation") outweigh this drawback.

In your case, it's probably safe to switch to `findall`.

Comment: Why does memory matter since by doing xmlroot we have already loaded the entire tree into memory?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it did, but even so, another list (with all the results) will be built by `.findall()` on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

As said in your link iterfind return a generator (yield) and findall return a list.

The only difference is there, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-iterator-and-a-generator) for example to see the difference between this two types.

It's mostly a memory performance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/xml/etree/ElementPath.py), you'll see that all of the functions `find`, `findall` and `findtext` are actually just thin wrappers around the main function `iterfind`. The source code is self-explanatory:

```py
def find(elem, path, namespaces=None):
    return next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces), None)
```

```py
def findall(elem, path, namespaces=None):
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
```

```py
def findtext(elem, path, default=None, namespaces=None):
    try:
        elem = next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
        if elem.text is None:
            return ""
        return elem.text
    except StopIteration:
        return default
```