# Difference between listing a generator and looping

Tags: python, generator

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790848/fastest-way-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-list), it seems that using a list comprehension (or `for` loop with `append`) is equivalent to calling `list(..)` on an iterator. Since [generators are iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022581/2682729) too, I'd expect the same for generators. However, if you run

```
def permute(xs, count, low = 0):
    if low + 1 >= count:
        yield xs
    else:
        for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
            yield p
        for i in range(low + 1, count):
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]
            for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
                yield p
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]

print("Direct iteration")
for x in permute([1, 2], 2):
    print(x)
print("Listing")
for x in list(permute([1, 2], 2)):
  print(x)
```

[It prints](https://repl.it/repls/YummyRedundantCybernetics):

```
Direct iteration
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
Listing
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying and yielding the same list `xs` over and over. When the generator is running the list contents are changing. It looks like it's working because although each `print(x)` prints the same list object, that object has different contents each time.

On the other hand, the second loop runs the generator to completion and collects all of the list references up. *Then* it prints out the lists—except they're all the same list, so every line is the same!

Change the two `print(x)` lines to `print(x, id(x))` and you'll see what I mean. The ID numbers will all be identical.

```
Direct iteration
[1, 2] 140685039497928
[2, 1] 140685039497928
Listing
[1, 2] 140685039497736
[1, 2] 140685039497736
```

A quick fix is to yield copies of the list instead of the original list. The `yield p`'s are fine, but `yield xs` should become:

```
yield xs[:]
```

With that fix, the results are as expected:

```
Direct iteration
[1, 2] 140449546108424
[2, 1] 140449546108744
Listing
[1, 2] 140449546108424
[2, 1] 140449546108808
```

Same results from both loops, and the ID numbers are different.